# Can't create some kinds of nodes from HTML strings using innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, validation, dom

The following javascript (run in the chrome console) does not do what I'd expect:

```
> var elem = document.createElement("foo");
undefined
> elem.innerHTML = "<tr></tr>"
"<tr></tr>"
> elem.outerHTML
"<foo></foo>"
```

The `<tr>` tag has disappeared!

This seems specific to table-related elements. Using `<div>` or `<span>` works as expected.

I expect what I'm doing is invalid, as "foo" is not a known element, and presumably table-related elements can only appear within a . Interestingly, the following code works just fine:

```
> var elem = document.createElement("foo"), tr = document.createElement("tr");
> elem.appendChild(tr);
> elem.outerHTML
"<foo><tr></tr></foo>"
```

So it seems like the construction itself (a `<tr>` not within a `<table>`) is allowable, but the method of using innerHTML to place it there does not work - perhaps this goes through some html cleanup, which removes things that are not strictly, while creating DOM nodes directly is not subject to the same validation.

My question: is there any way to populate an arbitrary DOM node from a string without running into such cleanup / validation issues? My use case will *end up* with perfectly valid structure (I plan to place this  as the child of a  sometime later), but the browser is stopping me while I'm trying to build the individual parts.

It sounds a little like DocumentFragment should be what I'm looking for, but as far as I can tell those are only constructable programmatically - they don't support innerHTML.

### some background on why I want to do this:

My use case is javascript-based live templating (i.e not outputting html strings, but actual DOM nodes). So the requirements are:

- template input must be allowed to be arbitrary HTML (this is why I'm using innerHTML and not constructing nodes programmatically)
- it must be possible to create sub-templates that are then attached into a larger document (that's why I can't just create the whole  at once).

The second point is how I encountered this bug. My template contains a sub-template.

```
var row = Html("<tr></tr>");
var table = Html(["<table><thead>", row, "</thead></table>"]);
```

I will later add code like:

```
row.append(Html(["<td>", column.header, "</td>"]));
```

to actually populate the columns. So when it's fully constructed, the html *will* be valid. But in the intermediate stages, each template / snippet is constructed under a single element. That means that templates like:

```
Html(["Hello <span>", name, "</span>"]);
```

still come out as a single node (so that they can be manipulated as a single entity):

```
<foo>Hello <span>bob</span></foo>
```

When the template results in only a single child inside the `<foo>`, the outer node is removed. But *during construction*, the `row` template above should look like `<foo><tr></tr></foo>`. Due to the validation behaviour I'm seeing when using innerHTML it just ends up as `<foo></foo>`.

I've checked all code works the same in both firefox & chrome, so I don't expect I'm just hitting a browser bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mihai Stancu's comment about jquery made me think: surely jquery manages this if you call `$("<tr></tr>")`. I know jquery has a shortcut for strings that look like single tags, but it must work for complex HTML as well.

So I took a dive into the jquery source code, and found just the ticket:

https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/6a0ee2d9ed34b81d4ad0662423bf815a3110990f/src/manipulation.js#L450

It's using a regex to detect just the name of the first tag in the string, then using this info to figure out what "context" it needs to wrap it in for the innerHTML process to treat it as valid. I think this technique should work for all well-formed inputs.

I've adopted this code into a standalone function which will turn an arbitrary string into a DOM node:

https://gist.github.com/gfxmonk/5299096

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the answer to your general question is no, there is no way to use `innerHTML` to add arbitrarily incomplete HTML fragments. I know this is not the answer you want to hear but that's the way it is.

One of the most misunderstood thing about `innerHTML` stems from the way the API is designed. It overloads the `+` and `=` operators to perform DOM insertion. This tricks programmers into thinking that it is merely doing string operations when in fact `innerHTML` behaves more like a function rather than a variable. It would be less confusing to people if `innerHTML` was designed like this:

```
element.innerHTML('some <b>html</b> here');
```

unfortunately it's too late to change the API so we must instead understand that it is really an API instead of merely an attribute/variable.

Now, to understand the so called "validation" behavior of `innerHTML`. When you modify `innerHTML` it triggers a call to the browser's HTML compiler. It's the same compiler that compiles your html file/document. There's nothing special about the HTML compiler that `innerHTML` calls. Therefore, whatever you can do to a html file you can pass to `innerHTML` (the one exception being that embedded javascript don't get executed - probably for security reasons).

This makes sense from the point of view of a browser developer. Why include two separate HTML compilers in the browser? Especially considering the fact that HTML compilers are huge, complex beasts.

The down side to this is that incomplete HTML will be handled the same way it is handled for html documents. In the case of `<td>` elements not inside a table most browsers will simply strip it away (as you've observed for yourself). That is essentially what you're trying to do - create invalid/incomplete HTML.

There are two work arounds to this:

1. Extract the table from the page then using string processing (regex et. el.) insert the `<td>` into the table string then `innerHTML` the whole table back into the page.
2. Parse the inserted HTML string and if you find any `<td>` or `<tr>` (or `<option>`) extract out the html element and insert it using DOM methods.

Unfortunately both are quite painful.

Comment: And both can ve easily overcome with the cunning use of jQuery and css  selectors.

Comment: Thanks for the great (and detailed) answer. It set me on the right track with the workarounds listed, which then pointed me to a less-painful (and more reliable) workaround from the jquery code.